# Vue JS: Passing the current object of loop on click

Tags: vue.js

I have a data where I am using loop. Admin will see a pop up if s/he clicks on the user section. I have following code:

**In user list page**

```
<template>
   <header class="headings">
    <div class="headings_title">
        <h3 class="text-center"> User List</h3>
        <div class="text-center" v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
          <div class="user-section" @click="showModel">
            <User :user="user"/>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
   </header>
</template>
```

The `User` component is working and user name, address has been displayed. But if the admin clicks on the particular user s/he has to be able to see other information related to the user s/he clicks. I want to pass `user` data in the modal also so that I can show other details related to the user. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple:

```html
<div class="user-section" @click="showModel(user)">...</div>
```

([See inline handlers in docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers))

Comment: the model is in another page so do I have to pass anything from UserList component and receive anything in UserModal component? Because simply doing this does not work

Comment: We don't know how your `showModel` function looks so it's kind of hard to say. Might be a whole new question.
Also: models and modals are not the same - take care which one you use.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please so and say if I am going right way.

Comment: This really was a whole new question, sorry. Look for "How to pass data to bootstrap vue modal". The "Passing the current object of loop on click" is answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271337/bootstrap-vue-how-to-pass-data-to-modal